# Fast way to find events that happened inside a time window with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, parallel-processing

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with events and their timestamp as follows:

| Event | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| Event 1 | 2023-04-02 11:49:14.122 |
| Event 2 | 2023-04-02 08:49:14.071 |
| Event 3 | 2023-04-02 08:49:15.507 |
| Event 4 | 2023-04-10 10:49:14.071 |
| Event 5 | 2023-04-10 10:49:21.164 |
| Event 6 | 2023-04-12 10:49:22.840 |

I am trying to find all the events that happened within 1 second of each other on the same date, for example between 10:00:00 and 10:00:01. I need to extract these events which will be further processed for some kind of pattern recognition.

I am  stuck with finding an efficient way. I extract all the unique dates from the dataframe, then iterate over dates, create a dateRange with 86400 seconds, iterate over each index with a 1 second window to search for the events.

The time stamps are not continuos and it is not possible to change the sampling rate of the original data.

I have currently gobbled up this inefficient code:

```
unique_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['occurence_timestamp_error_calc']).dt.date.unique()

for idxd in unique_dates:
    
    date_range_window = pd.date_range(idxd, periods=86400, freq='S', normalize=True)
    for window in tqdm(date_range_window):
        
        start_window = window 
        end_window = window+datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
        
        after_start_date = df["Timestamp"] >= start_window.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        before_end_date = df["Timestamp"] < end_window.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # '%Y-%m-%d %X'
        between_two_dates = after_start_date & before_end_date
        
        df2 = df.loc[between_two_dates]
        if(len(df2) > 1): #Find more than 1 event that happened in 1s time window
            #Extract the rows and add to a list
```

As alternatives, I have looked at the between_time() function but I guess there is a fundamental flaw with my approach.

I am looking for some inputs to getting this code run efficiently. Currently, each date of iteration takes about 10 minutes to run on a 8 core processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
# sort values and compute successive differences
# mark as True the differences ≤ 1s
m = df['Timestamp'].sort_values().diff().le('1s')

# select the matching rows
df.loc[m|m.shift()]
```

Example output:

```
     Event           Timestamp
7  Event 8 2023-04-12 10:00:05
8  Event 9 2023-04-12 10:00:01
```

Used input:

```
     Event               Timestamp
0  Event 1 2023-04-02 11:49:14.122
1  Event 2 2023-04-02 08:49:14.071
2  Event 3 2023-04-02 08:49:15.507
3  Event 4 2023-04-10 10:49:14.071
4  Event 5 2023-04-10 10:49:21.164
5  Event 6 2023-04-12 10:49:22.840
6  Event 7 2023-04-12 10:00:00.123 # ┓
7  Event 8 2023-04-12 10:00:05.000 # ┣ those 2 are within 1s
8  Event 9 2023-04-12 10:00:01.000 # ┛
```

Alternatively, if you want to make lists of close values:

```
(df.sort_values(by='Timestamp')
   .assign(group=lambda d: d['Timestamp'].diff().gt('1s').cumsum())
   .groupby('group')['Event']
   .agg(lambda g: list(g) if len(g)>1 else None)
   .dropna()
)
```

Output:

```
group
5    [Event 7, Event 9]
Name: Event, dtype: object
```